# android-webview not moving/panning/scrolling right and left

Tags: android, android-webview, android-websettings

I've a webview that I want to load a website and when I load it, it doesn't go right and left. It just goes up/down. (pan/scroll actions)

This is the code:

```
WebView wb=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
WebSettings settings = wb.getSettings();
settings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
settings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
settings.setSaveFormData(false);
settings.setSupportZoom(true);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve that with:

```
settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

But you should read more about it in Android SDK Documentation:

> public synchronized void setUseWideViewPort (boolean use)
>
> Added in API level 1 Sets whether the WebView should enable support
> for the "viewport" HTML meta tag or should use a wide viewport.
>
> When
> the value of the setting is false, the layout width is always set to
> the width of the WebView control in device-independent (CSS) pixels.
>
> When the value is true and the page contains the viewport meta tag,
> the value of the width specified in the tag is used. If the page does
> not contain the tag or does not provide a width, then a wide viewport
> will be used.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> use   whether to enable support for the viewport meta tag

More info @ 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setUseWideViewPort(boolean)

Comment: thanks for the reply , I use this , the problem is that it now want to show the whole website like a browser and there are lots of free and unused space on the page ,How to solve that ?

Comment: You can fiddle with setInitialScale or the zoom.Check @ http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#setInitialScale(int)

Comment: Or you can try: setLoadWithOverviewMode(true) in settings. In Docs you can read: "Sets whether the WebView loads pages in overview mode, that is, zooms out the content to fit on screen by width.". More @ http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setLoadWithOverviewMode(boolean)